# Odoo 9. Register payment error

Tags: odoo-9

I tried to register payment and received such error:

```
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: name - name]
```

In server log present such record:

```
2017-12-22 17:03:32,319 30901 INFO pr_odoo_v9 openerp.sql_db: bad query: INSERT INTO "account_full_reconcile" ("id", "name", "create_uid", "write_uid", "create_date", "write_date") VALUES(nextval('account_full_reconcile_id_seq'), NULL, 21, 21, (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC')) RETURNING id
```

How can  I fix it?  Why is field 'name' Null?

UPD: table account_full_reconcile has not any records

Answer (score 0):

are you testing any module? Or this is from the core? There is something wrong in the code probably, so update odoo or post your custom code please.

Comment: I think this problem in odoo because table account.full.reconcile has no records. In my test server what has 3 companies in it present 10 records from A1 to A10.
I nothing changed in payment(account) module.